# Use Stoke's Theorem to evaluate $ ∫_CF⋅dr $

Tags: calculus

Use Stoke's Theorem to evaluate $ ∫_CF⋅dr $ where $ \ F(x,y,z)=2xz \hat i+y \hat j+2xy \hat k  \ $ and C is the boundary of the part of the paraboloid where $ \ z=64−x^2−y^2 \ , z \geq 0 $ , where  C is  oriented counterclockwise when viewed from above .

**Answer:**

The projection of the surface $ z=64-x^2-z^2 \ on \ $ xy-plane is $ x^2+y^2=64 \ $.

I have calculated $ \iint_{S} curl \ F \cdot \hat n \ dS \ =\int_{0}^{8} \int_{-\sqrt{64-x^2}}^{\sqrt{64-x^2}}curl \ F \cdot \hat n \ dS $ .

**My questions is about the limits of integration ?**

**which is of the following is correct ?**

$
\iint_{S} curl \ F \cdot \hat n \ dS \ =\int_{0}^{8} \int_{-\sqrt{64-x^2}}^{\sqrt{64-x^2}}curl \ F \cdot \hat n \ dS   $

or

$ \iint_{S} curl \ F \cdot \hat n \ dS \ =\int_{-8}^{8} \int_{-\sqrt{64-x^2}}^{\sqrt{64-x^2}}curl \ F \cdot \hat n \ dS $ .

**Need help right at this point ?**

Comment: I believe you mean $z=64-x^2-y^2$ in your first line after 'Answer:'

Comment: I also believe it should be $-8$ to $8$ as the bounds of integration because the paraboloid will be symmetric and $-8$ works as well as $8$ in regards to the bounds permitted by the equation

Comment: (The name is Stokes, not Stoke.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ \iint_{S} curl \ F \cdot \hat n \ dS \ =\int_{-8}^{8} \int_{-\sqrt{64-x^2}}^{\sqrt{64-x^2}}curl \ F \cdot \hat n \ dS $ should be the correct equation because the bounds of the integral correspond to the symmetry of the paraboloid; the equation allows for $-8$ and $8$ to be values for $x$ and $y$ in the equation for the boundary $x^2+y^2=64$.